# Running Python on different machine

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have some code of python developed in PyCharm which I am trying to port to a Windows server.

The issue I am having is I move all the files (using Git pull) to the new server then run it, the code doesn't seem to be able to see any of the other files in the same folder.

I run the *.py* file using a windows command

```
C:\path\to\python.exe C:\path\to\py\files\main.py
```

If the `main.py` has simple lines such as

```
print("Hello World")
```

it works fine, however a command like

```
with open('./config.json') as f:
    config = json.load(f)
```

will give me a `FileNotFoundError`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Use an absolute path to your JSON file instead of a relative path.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out you can do it like this

```
import json
import os.path

my_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
path = os.path.join(my_path, "config.json")
with open(path) as f:
    config = json.load(f)
```

Answer (score 0):

> You are right but whenever you uploaded the code window os to server then file path is different because of os dependent so you can solve the above problem using

```
      os.path module in python
```

This is path mistake dependent upon the OS.

Answer (score 0):

It might me that your current directory is not set to the file location. An easier fix, especially if you try to import multiple local moduls: (Put this before any local imports)

```
import os
os.chdir(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)))
```